# Compare two strings character by character in C

Tags: c, string

I have one 'simple' (I hope) question. I am actually coding some little program and I need to compare two strings, same length, but different letters like

```
Eagle
```

and

```
Hdjoh
```

I want to compare the first letter of the first string with the first letter of the second string,
the second letter of the first string with the second letter of the second string etc..

I started to do like this:

```
for(i=0, i<N, i++){
        for(j=0, j<N, j++){
            if(string1[i]==string1[j] etc.. etc..
        }
    }
```

I see clearly that it doesn't compare first letter with first letter, second with second etc..

So maybe anyone have an idea how can I do this? (Without using any functions of string.h, i want to do this ''on my own'').

Maybe its a stupid question but im still a novice in C so...

Ah and the last thing, I define the two strings with 5 characters in my example, but it could be more than 5 vs 5..

Thanks by advance for the ideas.

---

Edit 1 :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 20

int main()
{
    unsigned char string1[N], string2[N];
    int Answer=0, i=0;
    scanf("%s", string1);
    scanf("%s", string2);

    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        if(string1[i]==string2[i]){
            Answer=1;
        }
        else{
            Answer=0;
        }
    }

    printf("Answer = %d", Answer);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why are you using a nested for loop for this? If both strings are of size n do this:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(string1[i]==string2[i]){
      //do something
    else if(// lesser than condition)
      //do something else
    else if(//greater than condition)
      //do something else other than the previous something
}
```

Here you when `i=0`, you are comparing `string1[0]` with `string2[0]`, when `i=1`, you compare `string1[1]` with `string2[1]` and so on.....

Comment: @user3605367 I would recommend you learn the use of the debugger in whatever IDE you use, it will be very helpful to trace what is happening in your program and you will easily be able to fix such errors by observing what is happening to the variables. Feel free to mark as correct answer!

Comment: @user3605367 the green check is for marking correct answer

Comment: Oupss. Yes sorry :) Done now

Comment: I made an edit on my first post (edit 1), with a new code, but this code always gaves me Answer = 1. Do you know why ? Thx. @Kartik_Koro

Comment: @user3605367 1 thing, this code will work only if BOTH strings are of length N. For example if you test with Eagle and Hdjoh after comparing uptil String1[4], String2[4] it goes on till String1[20] and String2[20], which may contain some garbage value and give you wrong results. What you would do is have something like int len1=strlen(String1) , len2=strlen(String2) after taking in the strings, then if(len1==len2) then for(i=0;i<len1;i++)//compare stuff here. Write now you are most probably comparing extra junk values

Answer (score 4):

Your approach with nested loops isn't very well thought-out.

Clearly it will compare *all* letters of the second string against the first letter of the first string, then do the same for the second letter of the first string, and so on. Not at all the desired behavior.

Re-implementing `strcmp()` isn't very hard, here's a shot:

```
int my_strcmp(const char *a, const char *b)
{
  for(; *a && *b && *a == *b; ++a, ++b)
    ;
  if(*a < *b)
    return -1;
  return *a > *b;
}
```

Note that it returns *zero* when the strings are *equal*. A good way to write a test is:

```
if(my_strmcp(a, b) == 0)
{
  printf("two equal strings: '%s' and '%s'\n", a, b);
}
```

Some people write it as `if(!my_strcmp())` but I don't recommend that, since it's mashing up so many concepts.

Comment: @chux Oops, didn't see that. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @unwind, thx for this, but yes like chux said I dont want to use strcmp for this..

Comment: @user3605367 But that would be *the* way to go... except if you want to learn.

Comment: @chux and he actually even provided a valid reason for that

Comment: @barakmanos Because I failed to realize there were constraints.

Comment: You haven't answered the real question here. Namely, why does using nested for loops not work!

Comment: Could simplify `for(; *a && *b && *a == *b; ++a, ++b)` --> `for(; *a && *a == *b; ++a, ++b)`.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the same index for both strings to compare:

```
unsigned len = strlen(s1);
assert(len == strlen(s2) && "Strings not the same length");

for (unsigned i = 0; i < len; i += 1)
{
    if (s1[i] != s2[i])
        return false; /* strings are not equal */
}
return true; /* strings are equal */
```

Make sure that the strings have the same encoding, either [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) or [UTF8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) or whatever. Comparing strings of different encoding will cause trouble :)

Comment: OP wanted "Without using any functions of string.h" like `strlen()`.

Answer (score 1):

This code compares character by character. Note that this is not suitable for crypto code as it is vulnerable to a timing attack

```
for(i=0; i<N; i++){
    if(string1[i]==string2[i]){
         equal = 1;
    }else{
        equal = 0;
        break;
    }
}
```

Notes:
I am assuming same length (as stated in question)
I am also assuming strings are non-zero length

Both of these assumptions may not be true in other code.

Comment: Which would be that timing attack?

Comment: Trouble if `N == 0`, `equal` is never set.

Comment: @glglgl The code breaks early if two characters are not equal. This means an attacker could use the time of this function to see where the strings are unequal.

Comment: @chux N couldnt be 0 :)

Comment: @user3605367 Why not, if you provide an empty string?

Comment: Hum.. didn't think about it in fact :s

Answer (score 1):

Simple compare each element until the end of string is found or a difference.

```
size_t i = 0;
while (string1[i] != '\0' && string1[i] == string2[j]) i++;
int StringTheSame = string1[i] == string2[j];
```

This ignores `N`, but stops when either end-of-string (`'\0'`) is encountered.

---

[Edit] @Kartik_Koro suggested a concern about a timing attack.  Following is a constant time solution

```
int diff_bits = 0;
for(size_t i=0; i<N; i++) {
  diff_bits |= string1[i] ^ string2[i];
}
int equal = diff_bits == 0;
```

The above has a problem if either string's length is shorted than N-1, but per OP's requirements, that *should* not happen.

Comment: And thx to @chux too for your help. I got it three examples, its clear now :)