# Copying a line from a csv file using pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I'm writing a program that is supposed to search for a name in a CSV file and copy the record (all the info on the same line as the name) that goes along with it.

For example, if CSV file contains:

```
Bob, 13, 12345612
Eli, 12, 21398743
```

I would input `"Bob"` to get the first line, and copy this into an array called `"record"`.

So far my code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void FindRecord(char *a, char *b, char c[]);

void main(void){

    char arrayName[100];
    char arrayNewname[100];
    char *name = arrayName;
    char *newname = arrayNewname;
    char record[1000];

    printf("Please input a name in the phonebook: ");
    scanf("%s", name);

    printf("Please input a replacement name: ");
    scanf("%s", newname);

    FindRecord("phonebook.csv",name,record);
    }

    void FindRecord(char *filename, char *name, char record[]){

    //Create temp array of max size 
    char temp[1000];

    //Open file
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
    //Make sure file exists 
    if (f == NULL){
        printf("File does not exist");
        fclose(f);
        exit(1);
    }

    //While 
    while(!feof(f)){
        //Read one line at a time   
        fgets(temp, 1000, f); 
        int i = 0;
        int *p;
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
            if(temp[i] == *name){
                record[i] = temp[i];
                name++;
            }
            size_t n = (sizeof record /sizeof record[0]);
            if(temp[i] == *name){
            *p = temp[i + n];
            }
        }
    }   
    printf("%s", record);
    fclose(f);
}
```

Basically, I've found Bob and copied Bob, but do not understand how to proceed using pointers (not allowed to use string.h) and copying the rest of the line. I've been trying to play around with the length of the word once Ive found it but this isn't working either because of pointers. Any help/hints would be appreciated.

Comment: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: See also [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

Comment: To compare strings use `strcmp` or `strstr` etc.

Comment: You can use strtok() to make your program more simpler.

Answer (score 0):

When you are not allowed to use `string.h` you have to compare strings char by char.
Start by having a loop to find the name.

See: [Compare two strings character by character in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24063156/compare-two-strings-character-by-character-in-c)

And then copy the rest of the record. Either char by char or with more advance functions like `memcpy`:
https://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/standard_library_functions/string_h/memcpy.php

Now who is `int *p` ?

You didn't initialized this pointer. You have to either malloc it or assign it to an existing memory.
See for more information:
https://pebble.gitbooks.io/learning-c-with-pebble/content/chapter08.html

I think you should read more about pointers and then things will work much better for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not being allowed to use `string.h` is a good exercise in computing the string lengths manually (necessary to remove the trailing `'\n'` from the lines read with `fgets`) and also a good exercise for manual string comparisons.

For example, if you are reading lines into `buf`, you can use a simple `for` loop to get the length of `buf`, e.g.

```
    int blen = 0;
    for (; buf[blen]; blen++) {}        /* get line length */
```

(**note:** you find the length of `name`, say `nlen` in a similar manner)

Then having the length in `blen`, you can easily check that the final character in `buf` is the `'\n'` character and remove it by overwriting the newline with the *nul-terminating* character, e.g.

```
    if (blen && buf[blen - 1] == '\n')  /* check/remove '\n' */
        buf[--blen] = 0;                /* overwrite with '\0' */
```

The remainder of your `findrecord` function is just a matter of iterating forward over each character looking for the character that is the first character in `name`. Once found, you simply compare then next `nlen` character to see if you have found `name` in `buf`. You can easily do that with:

```
            char *np = name,            /* pointer to name */
                *bp = p;                /* current pointer in buf */
            ...
            for (i = 0;     /* compre name in buf */
                i < nlen && *np && *bp && *np == *bp; 
                i++, np++, bp++) {}
            /* validate nlen chars match in buf */
            if (np - name == nlen && *(np-1) == *(bp-1)) {
```

One you have validated you found `name` in `buf`, simply copy `buf` to `record` insuring your *nul-terminate* `record` when done copying `buf`, e.g.

```
            if (np - name == nlen && *(np-1) == *(bp-1)) {
                bp = buf;
                for (i = 0; buf[i]; i++)    /* copy buf to record */
                    record[i] = buf[i];
                record[i] = buf[i];         /* nul-terminate */
                return record;              /* return record */
            }
```

Putting it altogether, you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum { MAXC = 100, MAXL = 1000 }; /* if you need constants, define them */

char *findrecord (FILE *fp, char *name, char *record);

/* main is type 'int', and has arguments -- use them */
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char name[MAXC] = "",
        replace[MAXC] = "",
        record[MAXL] = "",
        *matched;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : NULL;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    /* prompt, read, validate name */
    printf ("Please input a name in the phonebook: ");
    if (scanf ("%99[^\n]%*c", name) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input - name.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    /* prompt, read, validate replace */
    printf("Please input a replacement name: ");
    if (scanf ("%99[^\n]%*c", replace) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input - replace.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    /* search name, copy record, return indicates success/failure */
    matched = findrecord (fp, name, record);
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    if (matched) {  /* if name matched */
        printf ("record : '%s'\n", record);
    }

    return 0;   /* main() returns a value */
}

char *findrecord (FILE *fp, char *name, char *record){

    char buf[MAXL] = "";                /* buf for line */

    while (fgets (buf, MAXL, fp)) {     /* for each line */
        char *p = buf;
        int blen = 0;
        for (; buf[blen]; blen++) {}        /* get line length */
        if (blen && buf[blen - 1] == '\n')  /* check/remove '\n' */
            buf[--blen] = 0;                /* overwrite with '\0' */
        for (; *p && *p != '\n'; p++)       /* for each char in line */
            if (*p == *name) {              /* match start of name? */
                char *np = name,            /* pointer to name */
                    *bp = p;                /* current pointer in buf */
                int i = 0,                  /* general 'i' var */
                    nlen = 0;               /* name length var */
                for (nlen = 0; name[nlen]; nlen++) {}   /* name length */
                for (i = 0;     /* compre name in buf */
                    i < nlen && *np && *bp && *np == *bp; 
                    i++, np++, bp++) {}
                /* validate nlen chars match in buf */
                if (np - name == nlen && *(np-1) == *(bp-1)) {
                    bp = buf;
                    for (i = 0; buf[i]; i++)    /* copy buf to record */
                        record[i] = buf[i];
                    record[i] = buf[i];         /* nul-terminate */
                    return record;              /* return record */
                }
            }
    }

    return NULL;    /* indicate no match in file */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/findrec dat/bob.csv
Please input a name in the phonebook: Bob
Please input a replacement name: Sam
record : 'Bob, 13, 12345612'
```

**Non-Match Example**

```
$ ./bin/findrec dat/bob.csv
Please input a name in the phonebook: Jerry
Please input a replacement name: Bob
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.